# screen: how to turn on alternate screen?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, gnu-screen, iterm

When I work in terminal, I see the history of the last shell commands execution output. If I run vim, I see the file I open full screen. When I exit vim, I can see the history of the last shell commands again.

However, when I use vim from screen. I see the footprint of the file I was just editing on my exit from vim instead of the history of the last shell commands. **I'd like to see the shell's history though.**

**How can I achieve this behaviour?**

I used:

- terminal.app and iterm2.app
- tried switching xterm to xterm-256color (in iterm2.app)
- checking and unchecking "Save lines to scrollback when an app status bar is present" and "Save lines to scrollback in alternate screen mode" (in iterm2)
- adding termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@ to .screenrc (although it should be a solution to the opposite problem, but why not to try)
- sshing to linux machines and trying to use gnu-screen there

Up to now I didn't get the desired behaviour.

P.S.

I googled a bit and saw comments of people who try to solve the opposite problem:

[Many of you probably know the annoying behaviour of console-based programs like less or vi restoring the screen after exiting so that the text you just had there vanishes.](http://blogmal.42.org/tidbits/titeinhibit.story)

The main idea behind this behaviour is whether programs use alternate screen to save a picture of the shell history and show it when vim exits. Thus if one wants to solve the opposite problem, he should

[exorce the evil alternate screen](http://shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE :** I had forgotten about a feature of `screen` that disables alternate screen support by default.

Add `altscreen on` to your `$HOME/.screenrc` to enable it. This is probably all you have to do; all the messing about with `$TERM`, `$TERMCAP`, and `$TERMINFO` is probably unnecessary. I'll leave the rest of this answer here anyway.

I've had this in my own `.screenrc` so long it slipped my mind.

To enable this feature for the current session, type your `screen` escape character (<kbd>Cntrl-A</kbd> by default) followed by `:altscreen on` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Without this, `screen` won't respond to the escape sequences, even if they're defined in terminfo or termcap.

---

`vim` (and `less`, and most other curses-based full-screen programs) use the `smcup` and `rmcup` strings defined by the terminfo entry for your terminal. (These are referred to as `ti` and `te`, respectively, in the older termcap system).  `smcup` switches to the alternate screen, and `rmcup` switches back to the primary screen.

If your terminfo entry doesn't have these strings, programs won't be able to do that.

The screen command, by default, sets your `$TERM` to `"screen"`. Apparently the "screen" terminfo entry  doesn't have `smcup` and `rmcup`.

If you feel like hacking terminfo entries, you can modify your existing information for "screen" to add `smcup` and `rmcup`. You'll need the `infocmp` command to convert your terminfo to a text, and `tic` to convert it back to the binary form used by terminfo.

A simpler solution is to set your `$TERM` environment variable to whatever it was before you invoked the `screen` command. Almost all terminal emulators these days are based on the old DEC VT100, so they should be sufficiently compatible.

On my system, for example, when I login I have `TERM=xterm`; it's likely something else on MacOS. Within a `screen` session, by default, I'd have:

```
 $ echo $TERM
 screen
```

I could change it to `xterm` like this:

```
$ export TERM=xterm
```

(Again, replace "xterm" by whatever `$TERM` is on your system.)

You can also add

```
term xterm
```

to your `$HOME/.screenrc`. In fact `screen` has a number of options for tweaking your termcap/terminfo settings; `man screen` and search for "terminfo" for the gory details.

Comment: Thanks!  `altscreen on` in `$HOME/.screenrc` and `Ctl+A` -> `:altscreen on` is what worked for me.