# Make IDE's work better with Mac terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

If I want to scroll in vim it just scrolls through the log instead of scrolling in vim, and if I close vim it still shows the file in the terminal. Is there a way to fix this to make it behave more like it does on linux systems?

Comment: Try a different IDE or submit your issue to the developer to help fix the problem :)

Comment: emacs does the same thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling inside Vim in Mac's Terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727261/scrolling-inside-vim-in-macs-terminal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [screen: how to turn on alternate screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868652/screen-how-to-turn-on-alternate-screen)

Comment: OP appears to be asking about the alternate screen feature, not the mouse.