# How to display output of `git branch` on-screen in same CLI terminal?

Tags: git, shell, command-line-interface

My apologies, but I am having trouble phrasing my question. I'm running on CLI (`zsh` if it matters), using git version `2.20.0` and on macOS (think I've encountered it on my Ubuntu system at home too).

Question: How do you display the output of `git branch` on the same CLI screen? i.e. if I run,

```
$ git branch
$
```

it pops open a new screen/window (inside my CLI) showing me all my branches. Pressing `q` closes the screen and returns me to shell. The problem is that I do not remember the names of the branches I had! I want them printed on-screen!!

Ideal output,

```
$ git branch
* master
branch_01
branch_02
temp_branch
experiment_2_delete
$
```

A dubious work-around is to do the following,

```
$ git branch > stuff.txt
$ cat stuff.txt
* master
branch_01
branch_02 
...
$
```

But it creates a new text file in the current directory and that gets messy. Memory tells me that this used to be the way `git` worked. Something changed recently and it's driving me nuts! Is there any way to get back the old behaviour?

Comment: Basically, I want to ask how to print git branches on CLI, but that is not _exactly_ the issue and folks will get confused. Spent an *agonizing* 30-ish minutes typing this question in.

Comment: @phd reading that question (& answer) - yes, this is a duplicate. `git config --global pager.branch false` was exactly what I needed!

Comment: For the record; I did use the search feature, but couldn't find that question. It also didn't appear as an alternate question when I was creating this question.

Comment: That happens a lot with duplicates, especially when it's not clear what's going on, which is why duplicate questions aren't bad. I'd still recommend making sure your less setup defaults to using `-X` (and maybe `-F` too, and `-R` to make colors work).

Comment: You can also add 
`[core]
 pager = less -FRX`
in your ~/.gitconfig file.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually an issue with your pager (probably `less` these days).

Most terminal emulators offer the concept of an *alternate screen*.  Opening your editor switches to this alternate screen; text displayed in this screen remains in this screen, and *only* in this screen.  Exiting the editor switches back to the main screen, and the alternate screen text vanishes, so that you're back to your command-line session, without the editor's display cluttering things up.  Which is fine if that's what you wanted, and makes *some* sense when using the editor.

Unfortunately, the implementation here is to do this switching for *everything* that uses cursor-addressing modes, and `less` uses cursor-addressing modes.  So this means that piping output through `less` *also* switches to the alternate screen.

There are numerous work-arounds and fixes.  The simplest for `less` itself is to use the `-X` option, as described in [this bug report](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/563) and the `less` documentation:

> -X or --no-init
>   Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
>    strings to the terminal.  This is sometimes desirable if the
>    deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like
>    clearing the screen.

Note that Git defaults to running `less -FRX`, so if you (a) are using `less` and (b) are not getting `-FRX`, check to see if you've overridden the defaults, through `core.pager` (or `$GIT_PAGER`) and/or through the environment variable `LESS`.

Some users (including myself) really, really *hate* this alternate-screen switching and wish for our *editor* output to remain on the screen.  Here, a more powerful trick is to disable the alternate screen entirely.  This is harder, however.  See, e.g., [How can you turn off alternate screen in OSX's Terminal.app?](https://superuser.com/q/134598/941003)  Some people really, really *like* this behavior and want to turn it on when it's off: see, e.g., [screen: how to turn on alternate screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17868652/1256452) (which has more links to how to turn it off).

(I use the "decompile the terminfo, edit out the alt-screen escape sequences, and compile my own terminfo" method myself.)

Comment: this is an informative post, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370253/198660 is more of what I was looking for. Thanks @torek.