# Displaying git diff and git log output on a separate terminal screen

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log, git-config

After setting up new development environment I encountered a strange git behavior that I don't recall seeing in the past.

I am used to `git diff and git log` creating a new screen in the terminal and displaying their output inside (what **less** does by default, and I'm using it as my pager).

I can then quit and go back to my previous terminal state, with the command output gone. Now, however, output is printed right into the same screen as if it was **cat** (but with a pager). Any ideas how to fix this? Couldn't find any info online.

UPDATE:
Was able to fix this with @torek's help by setting `core.pager` to `'less -+F -+X'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `less` set to use `-X` now, when you previously had `less` set *not* to use `-X`.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54332364/1256452) to [How to display output of `git branch` on-screen in same CLI terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54331536/1256452).  Note that you can choose which pager to use, and/or whether to use a pager, too.  (Well, you noted this in your question.)

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be the case indeed. But how do I turn that option off? My `core.pager` is set to just `less -F`, while `$LESS` and `$GIT_PAGER` environment variables are not set.

Comment: And by the way, alternate screen is enabled in my terminal, less by itself behaves like expected.

Comment: If `$LESS` *isn't* set, Git sets it to `-FRX`, which enables those three options. You coud, for instance, set `core.pager` to `less -F -+X`, or (my preference) set `core.pager` to `less` and set `LESS` to `-FR`. The latter will affect other invocations of less, setting both `-F` and `-R`. (Git's sneaky "set $LESS if not set" thing is, well, sneaky.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `PAGER` environment variable. This controls which tools is used by various programs to page through output.

```
export PAGER=less
git diff
```

If this works for you, you can then set this as a permanent environment variable in various ways depending on your operating system.