# how to change the open the "git log" with other software instead of default less?

Tags: git

When I use the "git log" command to see the log, it open the log file with "less", which I think is quite inconvenient because you have to enter "Q" to quit the log and its content would disappear from terminal, unlike the output of "cat" command. Is there a way to change the "less" from other command line tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disappearing screen is a separable issue: see my answer to [How to display output of `git branch` on-screen in same CLI terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54331536/1256452)  Nonetheless, you can replace the pager with any other pager you like, by setting `GIT_PAGER` in your environment, or `core.pager` in your Git configuration, or `log.pager` in your Git configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Putting "[core]
    pager = less -FRX" in the .gitconfig file solves my problem perfectly.